# Editing header.phtml with an XML file

Tags: xml, magento, header, php

I'm working on a magento web site and I'm trying to do some changes on the header.

I want to add 2 blocks (module) that I've made.

Is there a way to add them without touching the `header.phtml` by putting :

```
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(' ') ?>
```

Is there a way using the XML files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one placeholder in header.phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
```

If you want to add some blocks to it just use this code:

```
<reference name="top.container">
   <block type="%MAGENTO_ALIAS_TO_YOUR_BLOCK%" name="block.some_name" template="path/to/your/template/file.phtml" />

   <block type="%MAGENTO_ALIAS_TO_YOUR_ANOTHER_BLOCK%" name="block.some_name2" template="path/to/your/template/file2.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. Because when we use the code `getChildHtml('abc')`, we need to assign the `.phtml` file in the name abc.

It's possible to add new links in Top links.